# ~800 постов в очереди late answers

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Очередь проверки [запоздалых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) забита старыми постами?

Их сотни! Что произошло?

Вызвано ли это багом в движке? Что делать с забитой очередью?

Comment: Запоздалые ответы. Тысячи их! :)

Answer (score 6):

На мете Stack Exchange [было принято решение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/248633) поднять порог репутации для попадания в очередь с 10 до 50.

Это привело к попаданию в очередь сотен старых вопросов. Ничего не поделаешь, придется постепенно ее разбирать.

Comment: *постепенно* — ха! надолго ли собаке блин? завтра разгребём.

Comment: прогноз оправдался — очередь уже пуста. ровно 500 проверок за сегодня.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, не ожидал :) качество проверкок, впрочем, под вопросом.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin но лично у меня закончилась и закрывалка, и лимит WLQ, и даже голоса за удаление.

Comment: насчёт качества: когда я утром приступил к разборке очереди (оставалось уже всего двести с чем-то проверок), все первые штук десять выполненных мною проверок относились к *unix*-тематике. я не думаю, что движок занимается пересортировкой и предлагает в первую очередь то, что более знакомо проверяющему. скорее — эти проверки были **пропущены** большинством проверяющих (как далёкие от знакомой **им** тематики).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin насколько я понимаю, движок сначала предлагает вопросы по вашим избранным меткам. На En.SO вечно пара сотен VLQ, но несколько первых всегда про Git достаются.